# With a 2019 MBP, are there any benefits to driving a 4K display via Displayport (1.4) vs HDMI (2.0)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport, hardware-recommendation

I have an [LG550 27" 4K monitor](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/09ac17f7) that has HDMI 2.0 and DisplayPort 1.4 connectivity.

When driving it from a MBP 2019, I can use my dock's HDMI-USB-C adapter or an USB-C to DisplayPort Female adapter and then use the monitor's delivered cables.  Neither adapters were very expensive, but they seem to do the work.

Are there are any practical advantages to using HDMI vs DisplayPort or vice versa?  Looking at a web page, a high definition (5K) painting and a text editor, I couldn't see much difference.  Both look pretty good.  Should I expect any difference?.  Does the CPU/GPU need to do any extra work to accommodate one port over the other?  I should probably check with Total War Warhammer 2 too, as that's a pretty demanding game graphically.

No intent to do monitor chaining, btw.

Answer (score 2):

## No

Freesync sometimes isn't supported over HDMI, but this monitor supports it. On top of that, macOS doesn't support Freesync anyways.

USB-C can "natively" use "normal" DisplayPort and HDMI in its [alternate modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB-C#Alternate_Mode_partner_specifications), so as long as your dock supports HDMI 2.0, there should be no differences. (N.b.: do note that this is is different from [DisplayPort++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#DisplayPort_dual-mode_(DP++)), but practically speaking, this doesn't really matter for your purpose.)